# How to pass cmd-line argument to a method in test_file (pytest)?

Tags: python, pytest, optional-parameters

I'm using pytest. Have two files, `conftest.py` and `Test1.py`. Need to execute specific method, before executing tests. Named it as `dummy` right now (if any suggestion to change it to `test_dummy` also fine).It totally works fine now. how to pass a `cmd-line` argument to this `dummy` method, which is called explicitly ?

**Test1.py**

```
import time

tmp1 = ""
tmp2 = ""

class Test1:

    def dummy(self):
        global tmp1
        global tmp2
        tmp1 = "Sometext"
        ts = int(time.time())
        tmp2 = tmp1 + str(ts)
        # Need this `ts` value to be passed from command-line and should be accessed in this `dummy`
        # And this dummy to be called before the execution of any tests.
        # Could have added this conftest.py , but my requirement is to create a folder by getting method names here. So making a  separate `dummy`


    def testA(self, set_up):
        val = set_up[0]
        logging.info(val)
        # Do - Something, call some function by passing the `val`

    def testB(self, set_up):
        val = set_up[0]
        logging.info(val)
        # Do - Something, call some function by passing the `val`

    def testC(self, set_up):
        val = set_up[0]
        logging.info(val)
        # Do - Something, call some function by passing the `val`


class Test2:


    def testA(self,set_up):
        val = set_up[0]
        logging.info(val)
        #Do - Something, call some function by passing the `val`

    def testB(self,set_up):
        val = set_up[0]
        logging.info(val)
        # Do - Something, call some function by passing the `val`

    def testC(self,set_up):
        val = set_up[0]
        logging.info(val)
        # Do - Something, call some function by passing the `val`


obj1 = Test1()
obj1.dummy()      #Explicitly calling it.

pytest -s -v test1.py::Test2
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

def tear_down():
    print "\nTEARDOWN after all tests"


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--a", action="store", default=None, help="value A")

    parser.addoption(
        "--b", action="store", default=None, help="value B")

    parser.addoption(
        "--c", action="store", default=None, help="value C")

    parser.addoption(
        "--d", action="store", default=None, help="value D") # Need this value to be available in `dummy`

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def set_up(request):
    print "\nSETUP before all tests"

    if request.function.__name__ == "testA": 
        return([request.config.getoption("--a"),request.config.getoption("--b"),request.config.getoption("--c")])
    elif request.function.__name__ == "testB":
        return ([request.config.getoption("--a"), request.config.getoption("--b"), request.config.getoption("--c")])
    elif request.function.__name__ == "testC":
        return ([request.config.getoption("--a"), request.config.getoption("--b"), request.config.getoption("--c")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as reference:

```
import sys


def dummy():
    print(sys.argv[0])
    print(str(sys.argv))


dummy()
```

Comment: pytest -s -v test1.py::Test2 --a valueA --b valueB --d valueD , in this case how will the values to be passed to 'dummy' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pytest_addoption](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html):

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--dummy", action="store", default="dummy")
```

which adds a new commandline option called `dummy` that can then be accessed in a fixture by:

```
request.config.getoption("--dummy")
```

e.g.

```
@pytest.fixture
def dummy(request):
    dummy_val = request.config.getoption("--dummy")
```

Note that making your dummy function a fixture in this way will allow you to run automatically before all tests, in the usual pytest fashion.

Comment: If you look at test1.py, how will you invoke this `dummy` method before any test execution ?

Comment: reason why i'm keeping `dummy` in `test1.py` is to make `dummy_val` a global variable and also `dummy` creates a folder by getting all the methods present in test1.py . Is this possible by making it in fixture ?

Comment: @StackGuru you could do something like `@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)`, which should make dummy behave the way you need, I think?

Comment: `dummy` is in `class Test1` and I'm passing all the cases of `Test2`, so explicitly calling dummy.

Comment: @StackGuru I'm not 100% clear on what dummy is supposed to be using, but it seems to me that it should live in your `conftest`. Check out [the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/special.html) for some ideas that may help you. I also don't understand the `set_up` fixture - it seems to be doing the same thing for all tests?

Comment: `dummy` > it fetches all the methods present in the same file (i.e., test1.py) and creates the folders of the same and sets some global variables. These folder paths and global variables will be used by tests throughout.

Comment: if it to made in contest.py, how would i retrieve list of all methods present in `test1.py` and global variable in `conftest.py` (set by dummy) and make available in `test1.py`

Comment: `set_up` fixture does the same and used to pass the parameters to respective methods (starting with test*).

Comment: @StackGuru the code you've posted doesn't look like it's fetching method names. Check out the link in my comment above - there are methods in pytest to get names of all tests that are currently running, which you could use to set folder names. I wouldn't recommend using global variables as it's generally bad practice for Python - it'd be better to pass data to tests via fixtures.

Comment: yeah, i haven't included fetching method names. Is this available in pytest ? can you point me to that if any examples ?

Comment: @StackGuru I posted a link in an earlier comment that should be able to do what you need